# Inserting a char to a matrix

Tags: java, matrix

I'm trying to insert a char into a matrix but there's an exception every time.

```
int rows, columns;

rows = 3;
columns = 3; 

char matrix[][] =new char[rows][columns];

System.out.println("Please insert '|' to go down '-' to go left or a to proceed");

for (int i = 0; i <rows ; i++) {
    for (int j = columns-1,k=0; j >= k; j--)
        matrix[i][j] = s.next().charAt(0);
}
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        System.out.printf("%d\t", matrix[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
```

Exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Character
>   at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
>   at java.io.PrintStream.format(Unknown Source)
>   at java.io.PrintStream.printf(Unknown Source)
>   at semester001.Question17.main(Question17.java:27)

Comment: What do you mean by "crash"? Throw an exception? Please post the stack trace and indicate the line on which it occurs.

Comment: `System.out.printf("%d\t", matrix[i][j]);` should be changed to `System.out.printf("%c\t", matrix[i][j]);`

Comment: change %d to %c in the `System.out.printf` should fix that error

Comment: thanks! whats the diffrence btw?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Comment: %d is used for integers, %c is for characters read more here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Comment: s.next() = letting the user insert a letter/number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.out.printf("%d\t", matrix[i][j]);`

Attempts to print an integer, what you want is:

`System.out.printf("%c\t", matrix[i][j]);`

Which tries to print a character.

Good resource on this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem is this line:

```
    System.out.printf("%d\t", matrix[i][j]);
```

the %d means you a printing an integer. %c should be used for chars. [Here's a link](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_formatted_strings.html) that explains the formatting for printf

Answer (score 0):

Changing %d to %c fixed the problem

```
Random dice = new Random();
int rows, columns;

rows = 3; // 1 + dice.nextInt(9);
columns = 3; // 1 + dice.nextInt(9);

char matrix[][] =new char[rows][columns];

System.out.println("Please insert '|' to go down '-' to go left or a to proceed");

for (int i = 0; i <rows ; i++) {
    for (int j = columns-1,k=0; j >= k; j--)
        matrix[i][j] = s.next().charAt(0);
}

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        System.out.printf("%c\t", matrix[i][j]);
    }

    System.out.println();
```